# How do I add a Domain Group as Sysadmin on SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: batch-file, automation, sql-server-2008-express, sccm, active-directory-group

Let me describe whats happening. I have an application which requires SQL Server 2008 Express. 
The application requires the AD-User to have sysadmin rights on the SQL Server. Both SQL and application is deployed using SCCM 2012 R2. My Problem is that when the SQL server is deployed it installs using the current user(System) as a sysadmin on the SQL Instance.

My application will not launch unless the Current user is a sysadmin. Is there anyway I can add an AD-group as a sysadmin on the SQL Server? Preferably using a command line (batch script).

Comment: I tried adding a local security group in my configurationfile for SQL Express, which worked on my test machine, but currently no luck with an Active Drirectory Group


`SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="WIN-E850MG68CCN\test"
ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN="FALSE"`

Answer (score 1):

IT worked with AD groups, turned out to be the strict password policy inherited by the domain and my user not having a strict password.

`SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS="ad\group"`